# Make wget not download files larger than X size

Tags: download, wget

Okay, I give up. How do I size limit which files are downloaded, like say I don't want any files bigger than 2 MB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only limitation option I know which `wget` supports is the `-Q` switch for quota. This is not what you want though, as it will stop after a **combined limit** of all files you've downloaded, not individually. Piping each link to it seperately with the `-Q` switch won't work either, as explained in the [**man page**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget).

I don't know what environment you're using, but [**crawler**](http://crawler.archive.org/) supports file size limitations with max-length-bytes and runs on the Java platform.

from their [**user manual**](http://crawler.archive.org/articles/user_manual/config.html#settings):

> - max-length-bytes
>
> Maximum number of bytes to download
>   per document. Will truncate file once
>   this limit is reached.
>
> By default this value is set to an
>   extremely large value (in the exabyte
>   range) that will never be reached in
>   practice.

Comment: Hmmm. Okay. That reiterated a lot of what I found out but good answer anyway. I didn't know that Heritrix truncated files instead of skipping them, though.

Answer (score 3):

If its about "*downloading 2MB max*" rather than "*download files with max 2MB*" you could just limit the output saved to disk.

`wget -O - $url |head -c 1024` (with an optional `> $SaveAsFile`)
-> saves the first KB and the rest gets truncated.

(enough to see a "*OK:$Message*", not killing my */tmp* with tons of error messages from the remote ;-))

Answer (score 1):

This possible with help of 3rd-party patches: http://yurichev.com/wget.html

Comment: Review [this post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225), you must.

Comment: @KronoS there's an "edit" button right there if you think the answer needs to be expanded. Personally it seems fine as-is, given that sentence #1 of the linked page explains the new option…